# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

i Have a grid name=gvDetails in that grid i have a dropdown also for page navigation

```
protected void gvDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow;
   DropDownList pageList =
```

> (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");

```
    Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");
    if (pageList != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.PageCount; i++)
        {
            int pageNumber = i + 1;
            ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
            if (i == gvDetails.PageIndex)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
            pageList.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (pageLabel != null)
    {
        int currentPage = gvDetails.PageIndex + 1;
    }
}
```

-----**************----------

This Is the fill coding i have

```
protected void gvDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
    Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");
    if (pageList != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.PageCount; i++)
        {
            int pageNumber = i + 1;
            ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
            if (i == gvDetails.PageIndex)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
            pageList.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    if (pageLabel != null)
    {
        int currentPage = gvDetails.PageIndex + 1;
    }
}
protected void PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
    gvDetails.PageIndex = pageList.SelectedIndex;
}
private void LoadBindGrid()
{
    ////Set your connection String here
    SqlConnection CN = DBUtil.GetCon();
    if (CN.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        CN.Close();
    CN.Open();
    string q = "SELECT Head_Code,Head_Name,Section_Code,Head_Mode,Head_Type,Head_Status FROM eLogs_Acc_Account_Master";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, CN);
    //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
    ////Write a select Query
    //string q = "select CustomerID,CompanyName,ContactName,Phone,City,Country  from Customers";
    DataSet dset = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q, CN);
    //cn.Open();
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dtable);
    //Bind grid.
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtable;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
    CN.Close();
}
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. IE., from line NO 4( DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");)
help please

Comment: Which line exactly? Obviously some variable is unset, but without knowing which one it's impossible to say **why**

Comment: DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList"); this line i have error

Comment: object reference arror i been cleared i want to bind data's in the grid how i should i bind the data

Answer (score 0):

Please check nulls and exit early. Here is what I mean:

```
protected void gvDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow;
    //-- quick exit if pagerRow not found
    if(pagerRow == null) return;
```

```
DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
if(pageList==null) return;

Label pageLabel = (Label)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("CurrentPageLabel");


    for (int i = 0; i < gvDetails.PageCount; i++)
    {
        int pageNumber = i + 1;
        ListItem item = new ListItem(pageNumber.ToString());
        if (i == gvDetails.PageIndex)
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
        pageList.Items.Add(item);
    }

if (pageLabel != null)
{
    int currentPage = gvDetails.PageIndex + 1;
}
```

}

Please note that above code is only correction to make sure you will never get object reference error, you have to make sure it works correctly by your self.

Happy coding

Comment: here data are not binded into the grid view,it shows empty grid

Comment: here i want to bind the data into grid how i want to bind the data into the grid help

Comment: I see, you can directly write pagerRow.FindControl directly

Comment: object reference arror i been cleared i want to bind data's in the grid how i should i bind the data

Comment: I would request you to create a fresh question with aspx and back end code and where exactly you are failing, this question is solved now

Comment: SqlConnection CN = DBUtil.GetCon();
        if (CN.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            CN.Close();
        CN.Open();
        string q = "SELECT Head_Code,Head_Name,Section_Code,Head_Mode,Head_Type,Head_Status FROM eLogs_Acc_Account_Master";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, CN);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(q, CN);
        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtable);
        gvDetails.DataSource = dtable;
        gvDetails.DataBind();
        CN.Close();

Comment: the above i have in the function   private void LoadBindGrid()
    { ...........
    } Here i want to bind data into the grid